# Get last one year records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

I am trying fetch last one year records from till date from SQL Server database.

For example today is 2020-May-28 then it should fetch records from 2019-May-01. But the date column in my database is stored as an integer.

I tried with the following query but its not working,

```
SELECT Ft.EmpCode, Ft.YMD 
FROM DADAILYF AS Ft
WHERE Ft.YMD BETWEEN CONVERT(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 112) - INTERVAL 1 YEAR 
                 AND CONVERT(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 112);
```

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Please show examples of what the dates look like.  Your data is a mystery.

Comment: Date column data type is integer and the values are like 20190101,20190102,20190103......and so on till today and it will add records everyday.

Comment: @aaa please [edit] your question with the new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example today is 2020-May-28 then it should fetch records from 2019-May-01

You are storing dates as integer numbers like `YYYYMMDD`. You could use arithmetics like so:

```
where ymd >= (year(getdate()) - 1) * 10000 + month(getdate()) * 100 + 1
```

The computation gives you the start of the current month on year ago, as n integer number (that is, 20190501).

If you want an upper bound (say, until today included), then:

```
where ymd
    between (year(getdate()) - 1) * 10000 + month(getdate()) * 100 + 1
    and year(getdate()) * 10000 + month(getdate()) * 100 + day(getdate())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. SQL is working great!!

Comment: for both queries getting same data till today it is fetching all records. Just wants to know why you are multiplying 10000 to year and 100 to Month?

Answer (score 0):

Just another option is `format()`.  Notice the `MM01') - 10000`

**Example**

```
Select *
 From  Yourtable
  Where YMD between format(getdate(),'yyyyMM01') - 10000 
                and format(getdate(),'yyyyMMdd')
```

**Returns**

```
YMD
20200515
```